# Java Spark count column's element frequencies

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, dataset

I'm trying to obtain a `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>` for an input Dataset (csv) having for each element (column of the Dataset) of the Map a Map with the element present in the respective column with the count of their occurrences.
So having an example input like this:

```
col1,col2,col3
a,1,c6
ab,23,c6
cd,23,c8
a,1,x
```

My output should be like:

```
{col1:{a:2, ab:1, cd:1}},
{col2:{1:2, 23:2}},
{col3:{c6:2, c8:1, x:1}}
```

I have a way to do this taking each column separately and using "countByValue" to count elements as Map, then store each Map as value in the Map of the columns.
Now I'm thinking about a way to speed up the computation by reading the file once and I've tried to use the "flatMapToPair" function on my file:

```
JavaRDD<String> fileRdd
```

like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> res = fileRdd.flatMapToPair(
    new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, String>() { 
        public Iterator<Tuple2<String, String>> call(String x) {
            List<Tuple2<String, String>> res = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> d =  Arrays.asList(x.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1));
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
                res.add(new Tuple2<String, String>(columns.get(i), d.get(i)));
            }
            return res.iterator();
        }
});
```

and then groupingByKey:

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Iterable<String>> groupMap = res.groupByKey();
```

Now I have a result like this:

```
col1:[a,ab,cd,a]
```

and I think I need another map reduce step to count occurrences, so this might not be the best way to reach my goal...

Plus I noticed that with just the first flatMapToPair computation on a file of 200MB I get out of memory after a time greater than the previous computation took to process the same file, so I might be doing something wrong with the flatMapToPair..

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution if you use DataFrame instead of RDDs.

```
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

// Read CSV
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().csv(fileName);
// Initialize ObjectMapper
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);

// Map for collecting column information
Map<String, Map<String,Long>> columnCountMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Long>>();
for (String columnName : df.columns())
    {
        // Group and count using groupBy function 
        // and then convert to JSON and collect as List
        List<String> jsons = df.groupBy(columnName).count().toJSON().collectAsList();
        try
            {
                Map<String,Long> countMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
                // Iterate through the strings/rows; 
                // map it to Map then collect values;
                // put them into the countMap
                for (String json : jsons)
                    {
                        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
                        String[] keyValues = map.values().toArray(new String[map.values().size()]);
                        countMap.put(keyValues[0], Long.parseLong(keyValues[1]));

                    }
                columnCountMap.put(columnName, countMap);
            }
        catch (JsonParseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (JsonMappingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
String output = "":
try
{
        // If you need to output as {col1:{a:2, ab:1, cd:1}},
        // {col2:{1:2, 23:2}},
        // {col3:{c6:2, c8:1, x:1}}
        output = mapper.writeValueAsString(columnCountMap);
}
catch (JsonProcessingException e)
{
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```